# How to Include a Helper Method from a Rails Engine (Spree) inside of another Rails Engine (AlchemyCMS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, rails-engines

What I've run into is this:

AlchemyCMS is a Rails Engine for allowing Rails applications to have a Content Management System. It also has a preview page where it can load up an iframe of the example page with the layout. The layout here is the Spree layout. I've modified Alchemy to be able to load up the spree application layout and not its default.

In doing so, it is *not* loading up the helper methods. I am currently receiving:

```
undefined local variable or method `title' for #<#<Class:0x007f8dcc359498>:0x007f8de17dd6a8>
```

Where `title` is the first helper method in the application.

I've tried 5000 different techniques to try to load in Spree's helper methods into AlchemyCMS and I just can't do it.

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben,

You could do so by either including Spree's helpers within your application controller or within the base Alchemy controllers.

There is an extension for alchemy and spree together, which does a similar thing here:
https://github.com/magiclabs/alchemy_spree/blob/master/app/controllers/spree/base_controller_decorator.rb

You will just want to go in the opposite direction so instead of decorating a Spree controller to add Alchemy in you would decorate Alchemy controllers to include whichever of Spree's controller helpers you need to use:
https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/controllers/spree/base_controller.rb

In this case you need to include the common controller helpers:
https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/core/controller_helpers/common.rb

EDIT:

```
Alchemy::BaseController.class_eval do
  include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers
  include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Store
  helper Spree::Core::Engine.helpers
end
```

Comment: [This is everything I did within my application which got it working.](https://gist.github.com/BenMorganIO/df8b501ce7f045e6f631) Even though I was including the `ControllerHelpers` class, I still had to separately include the `ControllerHelpers::Store` class.

Comment: I'll add store to ControllerHelpers.